# Re render when new element is added to object

Tags: reactjs, jsx

So in my jsx file, I've got 3 functions for building the page with the first one like so:

```
export function RevisionHeader( { object }) {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
     {Object.entries(object).reverse().map(([key, arr]) => {
    let revNum = revision + key;
    let id = "rev-" + revNum.replace(".", "-");
      return (
            <div key={key} id={id} className="rev-container">
                <div className="panel-heading title">
                    <a className="accordion-toggle rev-a" data-parent={"#" + id} data-toggle="collapse" data-target={"#" + id + "-body"} aria-expanded="true">Revision {revNum}</a>
            </div>
       <div id={id + "-body"} className="revision-body in" aria-expanded="true">
        <GetComments commentsArray = {arr}/>
        </div>
        </div>
      );          
    })}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

I have then created a class for rendering like so:

```
class Comments extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);   
        this.state = {Comments: filteredComments};
}

   render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <RevisionHeader object={this.state.Comments} /> 
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

and then I have a function for bringing it altogether:

```
function App() {
    return (
        <Comments />
    );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('my-comments'));


root.render(<App />);
```

Now for the comments object that I am using, I have a function for filtering it

And then I have an event listener for a save button to add to the object when someone is adding a new comment

```
const addNewComment = document.getElementById('save-comment');
addNewComment.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const ids = allComments.map(object => {
    return object.Id;
});
    
    const minorRevisions = allComments.map(object => {
        return object.MinorRevision;
});
    const localId = allComments[allComments.length - 1].LocalId + 1;
    const newId = Math.max(...ids) + 1;
    const comment = document.getElementById("txtComment").value;
    const commentDate = toIsoString(new Date());
    const newMinorRevision = Math.max(...minorRevisions) + 1;
    const newComment = {AttachmentId: null, Comment: comment, Commenter: {ItemId: '30837400-a72a-ec11-80d4-00155d006701', Name: 'Lewis Ross'},
    Id:newId, IsDeleted: false, LocalId: localId, MinorRevision: newMinorRevision, ParentCommentId: null, 
    Recipients: [],  Time: commentDate};  
    
    allComments.push(newComment);

    filteredComments = filterComments(allComments);
       
});
```

So at the moment when I am loading the page I am not getting errors, but the page is not updating whenever a new comment has been added, I am assuming I am missing something from my Comments class but I am just not sure what that it is? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Edit: So I have the event listener as the popup box where the user will enter a new comment is made up on a separate cshtml page, so I thought I would add an event listener for when the save button is clicked or should I be moving that box to my jsx file?

So basically the issue I am having is that I am wanting the page to render again when the filteredComments has been updated. I.e, so when a new comment has been added, the function RevisionHeader would be called again so that the new comment will appear on the page without having to do a full refresh

Comment: TLDR. Try to boil this down to just the issue you're having?

Comment: If this is react, why are you directly updating the DOM and using add event listener? I don't see a single useState in here.

Comment: Apologies for that, I think it's easier to understand now, let me know if I should still improve the question further